# Setting row's and column's to an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop, io

I am having an issue with my code counting the number of columns incorrectly.  I have to read from a text file the information regarding what I am supposed to have as my dimensions for a matrix but I seem to run into an issue with the column. The first digit is supposed to be the number of rows in the matrix.

What is on the input file:

```
3
8 5 -6 7
-19 5 17 32
3 9 2 54
```

Here is the code that determines the information:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("testwork.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        int numRows = in.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> columnCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {  
        columnCheck.add(in.nextInt());
        break;
        }

        int numColumns = columnCheck.size();

        System.out.println(numRows, numColumns);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

The output I get from this code is 3(Number of rows) 12(number of columns).  Obviously this is wrong and I know the issue is that the while loop keeps repeating to check how many numbers are in the loop but I can't figure out how to fix it.  What should I change with the while loop to have the program only take in 4 columns?

Comment: can't confirm: numColumns is 1, because you break

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're actually trying to achieve

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File("testwork.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
    int numRows = in.nextInt();

    ArrayList<Integer> columnCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int numColumns = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {  
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(in.nextLine());
        numColumns++;

        while (s2.hasNextInt()) {
            columnCheck.add(s2.nextInt());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(numRows, numColumns);
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
while (in.hasNext()) {...}
```

I believe the issue may be that hasNextLine() reads over the enter key "\n" which is why it is reading all numbers instead of one line. You will need another check after the line is complete with in.hasNextLine() to make sure you get to the next line in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

This while loop is wrong:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {  
    columnCheck.add(in.nextInt());
    break;
}
```

First get the the line and then store each of the integers in the ArrayList.

Do it like this:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {  
    String column = in.nextLine();
    String columnArr[] = column.split("\\s+"); // split it by space
    System.out.println("Column Numbers:" +  columnArr.length());
    break;
}
```